# Disabling null type in Newtonsoft JSON.NET schema

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, jsonschema

I have an MVC application, that serializes my model into json schema (using Newtonsoft json.net schema). The problem is that items in my array have type `["string", "null"]`, but what I need is just `"string"`. Here is code for my class:

```
public class Form
{
    [Required()]
    public string[] someStrings { get; set; }
}
```

This is schema made by Json.net schema:

```
"someStrings": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": [
      "string",
      "null"
    ]
  }
}
```

While I am expecting this:

```
"someStrings": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string"        
  }
}
```

Help me get rid of that "null" please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting `DefaultRequired` to `DisallowNull` when you generate the schema:

```
JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator() 
{ 
    DefaultRequired = Required.DisallowNull 
};

JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(Form));
schema.ToString();
```

Output:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "someStrings": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note this solution requires the Newtonsoft.JsonSchema package - this class is not available in the Newtonsoft.Json package.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
   [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
```

Comment: No changes from that :(

Comment: Do you do the serialization yourself? If yes, You could try this: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NullValueHandlingIgnore.htm

Comment: I guess I shouldn't use term "serialize" in my problem, because all I do is generating schema by my class. So answer is no, I am not doing serialization.

Answer (score -1):

Try this ::

```
     public class Employee 
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Age { get; set; }
            public decimal? Salary { get; set; }
        }    

        Employee employee= new Employee
            {
                Name = "Heisenberg",
                Age = 44
            };

            string jsonWithNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
```

### **output: with null**

```
// {
//   "Name": "Heisenberg",
//   "Age": 44,
//   "Salary": null
// }
```

---

```
 string jsonWithOutNullValues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employee, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
```

### **output: without null**

```
// {
//   "Name": "Heisenberg",
//   "Age": 44
// }
```